# Change nested row class onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having nested records which I want to change a picture on each row onclick of a class but with my current script nothing happens?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".star_gray").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('star_color');

    });
});
```

HTML

```
 <a href="#"> <div class="star_gray"></div></a>
```

CSS

```
.star_color {
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(../img/star_liked.png);
    width: 24px;
    height: 23px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    right:5px;  
}

.star_gray {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../img/star_not_liked.png);
    width: 24px;
    height: 23px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: in your css star_color stands before star_gray, place .star_color styles after .star_gray styles. @Pimskie's answer is right solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimize the CSS since, except from the image, it's completely the same:

```
.star_gray {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../img/star_not_liked.png);
    width: 24px;
    height: 23px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    right: 5px;
}

.star__gray.star_color {
    background-image: url(../img/star_liked.png);
}
```

By adding the extra `.star_color` class the image should be overridden.

**Edit:**

Now with fiddle and fancy images: https://jsfiddle.net/3mq5rarh/1/

Answer (score 0):

I will try:

```
.star_color {
    background-image: url(../img/star_liked.png) !important;
}
```

What happens is that after toggling `star_color` class, your `div` element will become `<div class="star_grey star_color">`. Therefore, you want your `star_color`'s background-image to override `star_grey`'s image by adding `!important`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, the image should be `star_liked.png` not `star_not_liked.png`. Should be working now.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use `!important`.

Comment: If OP knows how to use `!important`, then he will not have to post any more questions of this sort in the future.